# How to resolve duplicate packages due to interrupted yum update

Tags: centos, yum, gitlab

This morning I went to update gitlab-ce using yum on our CentOS6 server from 8.8.4 to 8.8.5.

Unfortunately about halfway through the first of the two gitlab-ce package install steps I accidentally mashed the pause-break key on my keyboard. The result being that yum stopped.

I tried several things - being a *nix amateur I started out with retrying the yum command, `yum update gitlab-ce` - which told me yum was locked. So I found the yum PID and tried the `kill` command which did not report anything, but then yum was still running when I queried `ps`.

I found `fg` to foreground the yum job again. But it stopped after completing the first of the two upgrade steps.

Thought I had resolved things then, using `yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only` which said it cleaned up a transaction journal.

But now, trying `yum update gitlab-ce` says 8.8.4 will be updated and 8.8.5 will be an update but the subsequent transaction check finds 8.8.5 is already installed and then stops. I still haven't seen it do the second of the two update steps.

A `package-cleanup --dupes` lists 8.8.5 *and* 8.8.4. The gitlab control panel still shows 8.8.4 and that I need to update. But a `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` command shows that gitlab is at 8.8.5 >_<

I am now not sure how updated or not gitlab is. How can I find out the state of the install and complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try purging the 8.8.5 from your rpmdb. Use `rpm -q gitlab-ce` to get the exact package name and insert it into the command below.

`rpm -e --justdb ${exact_package}`

Should look something like this

`rpm -e --justdb gitlab-ce-8.8.5`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you elaborate on what this will actually do?  (I'm pretty much a noob at *nix!)

Comment: Yum uses the rpmdb as its source of information. You're basically removing the .5 entry and leaving the .4 entry. When you re-run the update yum will be oblivious that it tried the upgrade and will start over.

Comment: Thanks Zachary! Am I right in thinking that check-packages also uses rpmdb as its source?

Comment: This did the trick by the way! To check out the rpm command I first ran `rpm -evv --test --justdb gitlab-ce-8.8.5` before then running the one in the answer. Running the `yum update gitlab-ce` command slowed on the completing transaction stage but then completed correctly and gitlab is displaying the correct versions all round :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)